# Can someone explain the difference between @Remote / @Local or only @Stateless in ejb?

Tags: ejb, local, stateless

I guess the topic says it.
I have tried googling this, but havent gotten the answer I am looking for.

I have many EJB's with only @Stateless.
And sometimes I put @Local on them withouth really knowing why, and the benefits/cons. I also know I can put @Remote, but really dont know the difference.

Hope someone can give a clear description, or point me somewhere that does.

Comment: A good summarising answer is here:
http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/localremote.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations are part of EJB 3.0. For ex. @stateless means it is a stateless session bean. @local is used for local interface and @Remote for remote bean interface. A detailed description of the anotations is given [here](http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs100/ejb30/annotations.html#wp1416811). To understand the meaning of these terms though, you should refer to a manual or book on EJBs. You can download a good EJB 3.0 book from [here](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/wiley/masteringEJB3/index.tss). Also checkout [EJB 3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/panda/) from Manning Pub.

Comment: that's not a  clear answer and pointing to a book is not the easiet way to understand